# Nesting a table, column of type string in BigQuery

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery

I have a query that I am running against my dataset in BigQuery. The data is partly the google analytics data for a particular website.
I want to be able to nest the string values for my key_web, to simplify the output and get the option to go deeper in detail if I want to.
The prd.key_web is of type string.
I have no idea how to do it !
It is a one to many relationship between the user who can have multiple rows in the table.
All fields are of type string except for prd.dat_log.

A simpler query would be:

```
 select
        prd.key_web
        , dat_log AS date
        , prd.nrb_fp AS nrb_fp
        , prd.tps_fp AS tps_fp
        , prd.univ
        , prd.suniv
        , prd.fam
        , prd.sfam
    from product as prd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `ARRAY_AGG` function can create nested array in aggregation

```
select
  prd.key_web,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
    dat_log,
    prd.nrb_fp,
    prd.tps_fp,
    prd.univ,
    prd.suniv,
    prd.fam,
    prd.sfam)) AS details
from
  product as prd
group by
  key_web
```

Comment: what if I had other 'as' for the columns that would be inside the ARRA_AGG, is there a way to modify it because it didn't work for me !

Comment: I used your solution and deleted my AS inside the query but I keep getting an error:         
No matching signature for aggregate function ARRAY_AGG for argument types: STRING, STRING, DATE, STRING, STRING, STRING, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64. Supported signature: ARRAY_AGG(ANY)

Comment: Ah! sorry for missing important syntax, When you want to aggregate multiple values inside ARRAY_AGG, we should use ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value1, value2, value3...))，please have a look ~!

Comment: Now, it works for me. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction !